# How to gracefully change a long chained on promises to be parallel in typescript?

Tags: typescript

The original code is like:

```
new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
    resolve();
})
.then(() => {
    return 1;
})
.then((res1) => {
    return res1 + 1;
})
.then((res2) => {
    return res2 + 1
})
.then((res3) => {
    return res3 + 1
})
.
.then((sum) => {
    console.log("I am the end! the sum is " + sum);
})
```

But the code is growing longer so I want to use `Promise.all()`; So the procedure should be:

1. init
2. do all calculation in parallel(the sequences doesn't matter)
3. sum them up in final

How to properly achieve that? Can I make each stage as a standalone function to be more readable?

If I use `Promise.all()`, do I have to pass an array of promises?

Comment: It's not clear how `Promise.all` would help when this example relies on the promises resolving in-order, requiring the previous promise to resolve before the current one can resolve. Consider using async/await to simplify this code.

Comment: @spender Well you are right definitely not a good example. But I want to express the sequence doesn't matter since the result will be same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using `Promise.all()` to wait for all calculations to compute and then using `Array.reduce()` to add all the results up to a sum.

```js
const originalPromise = new Promise(resolve => resolve());

const firstCalculation = new Promise(resolve => resolve(1));
const secondCalculation = new Promise(resolve => resolve(2));
const thirdCalculation = new Promise(resolve => resolve(3));
const fourthCalculation = new Promise(resolve => resolve(4));

Promise.all([
    firstCalculation,
    secondCalculation,
    thirdCalculation,
    fourthCalculation
]).then(results => {
    const sum = results.reduce((acc, current) => acc += current, 0);
    console.log(`The sum is ${sum}`);
});
```

Comment: Hi @Yanick Bélanger, I met a problem using this way. Since in the beginning every stage will return an array I just simply add it every time. But now the return type is weird(not a flat array anymore).. How can I flat them?

Comment: @Michael simply add `.flatMap(it => it)`before `.reduce`

Comment: @Minami Thanks! I found `[].concat(...a, ...b)` also works.